# Create DataExchange Product Dynamically (API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

Is there any API to create DataExchange Product dynamically?
If not can [this service catalog API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/dg/API_CreateProduct.html) be used with some CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 13th July 2022, AWS Data Exchange does not have API support for creating AWS Data Exchange Product.

Service Catalog Product is different to a Data exchange product, so [this service catalog API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/dg/API_CreateProduct.html) cannot be used.